# array_replace_recursive unexpectedly deletes array values

Tags: php, arrays, merge, comparison

I need to get an array for every countries' turnover. Please see the structure of the arrays here, the question comes after the array structure.

Structure 1, `$this->allTurnovers`:

```
array:5 [▼
  1 => array:54 [▶]
  2 => array:48 [▶]
  3 => array:52 [▶]
  4 => array:3 [▶]
  5 => array:6 [▶]
]
```

Here is `$this->allTurnovers[5]` collapsed:

```
array:5 [▼
  1 => array:54 [▶]
  2 => array:48 [▶]
  3 => array:52 [▶]
  4 => array:3 [▶]
  5 => array:6 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-08"
      "Amount" => "23.65"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-10"
      "Amount" => "14.91"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-15"
      "Amount" => "33.07"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "PurchaseDate" => "2015-01-11"
      "Amount" => "14.99"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      "PurchaseDate" => "2015-01-17"
      "Amount" => "65.96"
    ]
    5 => array:2 [▼
      "PurchaseDate" => "2015-01-25"
      "Amount" => "25.52"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Then, I have an array with all dates in a given amount of time, `$this->allTimes`:

```
array:54 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-06"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-07"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-08"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-09"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-10"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-11"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  6 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2014-12-12"
    "Amount" => 0
  ]
  .....
  .....
  .....
  53 => array:2 [▼
    "PurchaseDate" => "2015-01-28"
    "Amount" => 0
   ]
]
```

I need a Date and a Amount for every day in the timeframe, so I try to combine `$this->allTurnovers` with `$this->AllTimes`. I'm doing this with

```
array_replace_recursive();
```

Here's the function:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $this->allTurnovers = (new GetTurnoverForAllParticipations())->run();
    $this->allTimes = (new MaxAndMinTimeForTurnoverChart())->getMinAndMax();

    foreach($this->allTurnovers as $turnover)
    {
        $replace[] = array_replace_recursive($this->allTimes, $turnover);
    }

    list($de,$fr,$uk,$es,$it) = $replace;

    $test = json_encode($it);
    dd($test);
}
```

$this->allTimes originally holds an amount of zero for every date which gets replaced according to the amount of `$this->allTurnovers`.

It seems to be working for countries in which a turnover was made every day within the frame, but for example `$this->allTurnovers[5]` only has a turnover value for 6 days within the frame. The json encoded output is this:

```
"[{"PurchaseDate":"2014-12-08","Amount":"23.65"},{"PurchaseDate":"2014-12-10","Amount":"14.91"},{"PurchaseDate":"2014-12-15","Amount":"33.07"}.....
```

Basically it strips all the dates between two dates on which turnover was made. I can't really understand why this is happening...

> [The documentation states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)
>
> array_replace_recursive() replaces the values of array1 with the same
>   values from all the following arrays. If a key from the first array
>   exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value
>   from the second array. If the key exists in the second array, and not
>   the first, it will be created in the first array. **If a key only
>   exists in the first array, it will be left as is.** If several arrays
>   are passed for replacement, they will be processed in order, the later
>   array overwriting the previous values.

**So in short, the questions:**

- According to the documentation, where's my error?
- Why does array_replace_recursive strip the dates between replaced array entries?
- What can I do to merge the arrays the way I need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_replace_recursive()` method is doing what it says it does. It is replacing entries based on the array keys. The issue here is that your arrays aren't keyed like you need them to be.

`$this->allTimes` is an array with the keys 0, 1, ..., 53. `$this->allTurnovers[5]` is an array with the keys 0, 1, ..., 5. This gives you the following results:

```
$results = array_replace_recursive($this->allTimes, $this->allTurnovers[5]);

// equivalent to:

$results = array(
    0 => $this->allTurnovers[5][0],
    1 => $this->allTurnovers[5][1],
    2 => $this->allTurnovers[5][2],
    3 => $this->allTurnovers[5][3],
    4 => $this->allTurnovers[5][4],
    5 => $this->allTurnovers[5][5],
    6 => $this->allTimes[6],
    7 => $this->allTimes[7],
    ... => $this->allTimes[...],
    53 => $this->allTimes[53]
);
```

If you rekeyed the arrays using the dates, then this method would work. However, if you can't do that, you'll need to move to a manual foreach method where you can compare the dates and replace as needed.

Assuming you can't change the ways the arrays are generated/stored, you could do something like:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $this->allTurnovers = (new GetTurnoverForAllParticipations())->run();
    $this->allTimes = (new MaxAndMinTimeForTurnoverChart())->getMinAndMax();

    // PHP >= 5.5.0
    $keys = array_column($this->allTimes, 'PurchaseDate');
    // PHP < 5.5.0
    //$keys = array_map(function ($v) {
    //    return($v['PurchaseDate']);
    //}, $this->allTimes);
    $allTimes = array_combine($keys, $this->allTimes);

    foreach($this->allTurnovers as $turnover)
    {
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        $keys = array_column($turnover, 'PurchaseDate');
        // PHP < 5.5.0
        //$keys = array_map(function ($v) {
        //    return($v['PurchaseDate']);
        //}, $turnover);
        $rekeyedTurnover = array_combine($keys, $turnover);

        $replace[] = array_replace_recursive($allTimes, $rekeyedTurnover);
        // use array_values() if you want to get rid of the date keys again
        //$replace[] = array_values(array_replace_recursive($allTimes, $rekeyedTurnover));
    }

    list($de,$fr,$uk,$es,$it) = $replace;

    $test = json_encode($it);
    dd($test);
}
```

Comment: Very right, I've re keyed the arrays, now it is working as supposed. Thank you for your detailed answer!